# When I create 2 test case and record, it works fine individually but when I make them as 2 shared scripts it fails

Tags: mtm, coded-ui-tests

When I create 2 test cases and run individually in MTM it works fine but when I make them as shared script and put them in one single script file and try to run it. It types same character in the input text box again and finally fails.

for ex : instead of typing "Software" it types "SSSoooftware" some thing like that and fails the test.

Comment: Can you tell me if you are using Shared Parameters or non-shared parameters in your test cases?

Comment: Non-shared parameters.

Comment: Can you add some more information on exactly what you have done? As I have implemented the same few weeks back and it was working fine. After your question I have implemented the same thing and it is working fine. What I have done is:
Create 3 shared test cases with 4-5 steps and 2-3 parameters in each test case. Then, I recorded these shared test cases. After that I used them in a new test case by adding them as Shared steps in new case. Then, I run that new test case with existing recording and it got executed successfully, without any issue.
Have you done anything different from this?

Comment: I did the same thing. Actually it work fine some times and some times it fails by repeating the same character again. ex: to type "Software" it types 
"SSSooofttwaaree". I don't know may be it is because of my slow laptop or website loading speed.

Comment: Performance of system and application can be reason for this issue, because I know that playback feature sometimes creates this kind of issues. I have faced this issue with Telerik's Test Studio record and playback feature too. Try on different machine with same test case.